# ¿Cómo hacer upload de multiples archivos en Laravel, con el nombre original de cada archivo y por FTP?

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo el siguiente codigo de Laravel 5.8 que recibe un array de files, pero que esta subiendo el archivo al servidor con el nombre hasheado, y lo que necesito es que respete para cada archivo el nombre que ya tiene originalmente.

agrego storage

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
```

recibo los 3 archivos

```
$misdoc=$request->file('estadoc');
```

recorro los archivos, por cada uno, guardo

```
foreach($misdoc as $qdoc => $eldocu){

  Storage::disk('otroftp')->put('/carpeta', $eldocu); 

}
```

Comment: Prueba con `Storage::disk('otroftp')->putFileAs(
    'carpeta', $eldocu, $eldocu->getClientOriginalName()
);`

Comment: si, funciono perfecto. gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me funciono esto, aportado por el usuario porloscerros:

```
Storage::disk('otroftp')->putFileAs('carpeta', $eldocu, $eldocu->getClientOriginalName() );
```

Comment: Entonces considero deberías marcar la respuesta de el como aceptada en lugar de publicar otra respuesta

Comment: el usuario que contesto adecuadamente, lo puso en un comentario, no como respuesta, y el sistema me impide hacer lo que bien me indicas.

Answer (score 0):

Esta parte la puedes dejar igual, recibes los 3 archivos y los asignas a la variable `$misdoc`. Luego recorres los archivos recibidos:

```
$misdoc = $request->file('estadoc'); 

foreach($misdoc as $qdoc => $eldocu){

  // ...

}
```

Y, por cada archivo que se guardará en la variable `$eldocu`, (dentro del `foreach`) puedes:

**Obtener el nombre original del archivo**

Si deseas obtener el nombre original del archivo cargado, puedes hacerlo utilizando el método `getClientOriginalName`:

```
$nombre = $eldocu->getClientOriginalName();
```

Y para usarlo tendrás que usar alguno de los métodos que te lo permitan.

**Especificar un nombre de archivo**

Si no deseas que un nombre de archivo se asigne automáticamente a tu archivo almacenado, puede usar el método `storeAs`, que recibe la ruta, el nombre del archivo y el disco (opcional) como argumentos:

```
$eldocu->storeAs(
    'carpeta', $nombre, 'otroftp'
);
```

O también puedes usar el método `putFileAs` en la facade `Storage`, que realizará la misma manipulación de archivos que el ejemplo anterior:

```
Storage::disk('otroftp')->putFileAs(
    'carpeta', $eldocu, $nombre
);
```

---

*R̲e̲f̲e̲r̲e̲n̲c̲i̲a̲s̲*:

#### File Storage [File Uploads](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#file-uploads)